# How to make sure that the bot does not click on those people that it is already subscribed to

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I write a bot on Python with the selenium library under instagram. How to make sure that the bot does not click on those people that it is already subscribed to.Thank you in advance)

Comment: Welcome to SO! and congrats on choosing a awesome screen name. But can you please share some more details like what you have tried ? What issue you have faced ? etc. etc. Also give read to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask